# MS-Access Pivot Chart

Tags: excel, sorting, ms-access, charts, pivot

Could someone help me to sort and arrange the Pivot Chart in MS-Access please. I could do this easily in MS-Excel, but not in MS- Access. I need a gap in between each Task + Budget in MS- Access chart exactly as in MS- Excel. If you put a blank record in Access table, then sorting becomes an issue. Actually the sorting of X axis is not flexible enough in MS-Access and it simply sorts alphabetically. Thanks [image]

Comment: Forgive a stupid question here, my experience is also low. What would happen if you included in task a value like a space " " with an amount of 0?

Comment: I've come up only with adding record in table with value in `Task` column: `Task 1 End` and other columns blank. It solves issue with sorting, but adds `Task 1 End` in X axis of chart..

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to implement Sten's solution.
 Create another column in the query, and union it with the existing data

```
Select
    Replace(Task," Budget","") as TaskGrp,
    Task,
    Employee,
    Amount
From Table1

Union

Select 
    Replace(Task," Budget","End") as TaskGrp,
    Null,
    Null,
    Null
From Table1
Where instr(Task,"Budget") > 0

Order By TaskGrp, Task, Employee
```

Then omit TaskGrp when doing the chart

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, what I mean is add the value of a space. " ". Technically the space will show in the graph but no one will be able to see it. You can have an extra column which doesn't go into the graph for sorting.